# What transparent / Opacity Background Codes are compatible with ALL browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, opacity, background-color

I am creating a web page that contains an input field element. The input field element is inside of a div who's background is blue. I want the input field to be white, but also transparent so that part of the blue background in the div is visible. I also would like white text in the field as well. How do I code this in CSS so that it is compatible with all browsers?

Comment: @alex I would say the browsers that most common sites use (like Facebook, Twitter, Stack Overflow, Yahoo, etc.)

Comment: What about IE7?  Many big sites (Facebook, Google, YouTube) don't support it anymore, but it's not quite dead yet.

Comment: @tuff. I think IE7 would work just fine.

Comment: Google searchers: Please note: don't use background: transparent; it's CSS3 and not compatible with all browsers. just use background-color: transparent;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally clear which browsers you're looking to support - if you mean just all the *modern* browsers then you wouldn't be particularly concerned about compatibility - but anyways:

`background-color: transparent;` should work just about anywhere.

If you want an entire element to be partially opaque then you can use `filter` for IE8 and `opacity` for everything else, as shown [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/).

If you want to be able to set `background-color` (or any other colour) to a partial-opacity colour, you can use rgba, eg: `color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);`.  More info + support tables here [here](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).  Spoiler: it doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Perfect Tuff! Just the info I was looking for.